# How to call another cordova plugin from an android cordova plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

What would be the best way to call another cordova plugin in android?

I want to have a background service that calls a server for some information and based on that information, I need to do for example set a badge.

I found a Cordova Background Services Plugin, https://github.com/phpsa/cbsp
that could work well for my purposes and the use it with https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge among others.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to do it? Can I just include the classes and call them straight from my java code or is there something else that is required?

Looking for guidance on best approach.

EDIT: So apparently this isn't really a option. I managed to include the other plugin in my java code and I was able to call it, but ran into issues with CallbackContext, which is created by cordova platform when calling a plugin from javascript. This was basically a design feature of the badge plugin

The only way I found to implement the features I needed was to take the code from the other plugin and refactor it into my background service.

Answer (score 2):

For example:
`public class OtherPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{
 @Override
    protected void pluginInitialize() {
   YourClassPlugin yourClassPlugin = (YourClassPlugin)this.webView.getPluginManager().getPlugin("YourClassPlugin");
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

And why can you use javascript as a glue? Simply passing result of one plugin into another.

But when you have to do it natively, then you should do it via intents and BroadcastReciever. 
    http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Keep in my mind that receiving plugin has to have some kind of implicit intent defined. Check tutorial, there is all you need to know.
   http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: I was creating a background service that would run even when the main app itself isn't open which means that using javascript to call other plugins ins't an option. The badge plugin was offering the kind of functionality that I needed. In the end I found a third party library that gave me all needed options.

Comment: I need to do the same, are you able to share which library you ended up using?

Comment: @TarmoLehtonen - would you mind sharing the name of the 3rd party library that you used?

Comment: I used this one: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger
Has been working pretty well so far