# How can I call another plugin in Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: java, android, cordova

How could I go about calling another Plugin from a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin?

I'm writing a background service in PhoneGap and would like to retrieve data that is returned from another [plugin](https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble/). Because the service is running even when the application is not active on the screen, other plugin's cannot be called simply via Javascript.

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962062/how-to-call-another-cordova-plugin-from-an-android-cordova-plugin) that answer this just say that you should do it via "intents and BroadcastReciever" with no additional information or examples which doesn't help me solve the problem.

Thanks.